# How to convert multiple sentences into a list of list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe named final where I have a column named CleanedText in which i have user reviews(Text). A review is of multiple line. I have done preprocessing and removed all commas, fullstops,htmltags,etc. So the data looks like, Review1(row1): pizza extremely delicious delivery late. Just like this, i have 10000 reviews(corresponding to 10000 rows). Now I want a list of list where every review should be in a list. Ex: [['Pizza','extremely','delicious','delivery','late'],['Tommatos','rotten'......[]...[]].

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python split string list", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Please only use tags that are really relevant to your questions (machine-learning, word2vec, tf-idf *removed*).

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you've truly stripped the text of all of the 'fun' stuff.  Give this a shot.

```
fulltext = 'stuff with many\nlines and words'
text_array = [line.split() for line in fulltext.splitlines()]
```